# CiviMail not sending mails in 4.7.6 / Drupal 7 "DB Error: syntax error"

Tags: civimail

Since upgrading to 4.7.6 we have two CiviMail bulk emails with the status "Running" that have not actually been sent.  In the scheduled jobs log there is this message:

> Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure,
>   Error message: DB Error: syntax error
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:  Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with
>   result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error

In ConfigAndLog The [full error is shown here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KR1HNi6tYjYaays4X97nTnTP3fLqROhDaDKPAI9kgSU/edit?usp=sharing), but I'm struggling to locate the actual fault / corrective action.  Any help greatfully received.

Comment: Yes, there are CiviCRM-specific logs that will shed more light on the error. The location is different based on what CMS you are using. Can you update your description to include whether you are running Joomla, Drupal, or WordPress?

Comment: Thanks, have updated to show it is Drupal 7 and have found a fuller error in ConfigAndLog, which I have put in the updated post above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll notice (as per your Google Doc you posted), the last `VALUE` that the query is trying to insert is `( 1668, , 3537, null, '78ed5224ae6ab7d9' )`.  The second argument is missing, and therefore the Query is invalid.

Double check if Contact with ID `3537` has an email address associated with it.  I don't know why Civi wouldn't catch this error, but that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thank you Brad, that was it! Really appreciate your assistance :)

Comment: Perhaps the email address was deleted for that contact record after the mailing was queued? Would be good to think about why that might have happened.

Comment: @lcdservices I think that is exactly what happened - the contact in question had left her company, and our team dealt with that by deleting her email address from her record.  We are retraining the team!