# Cron Error/CiviMail Stalled

Tags: civimail, drupal, cron-job, 4.7.1

Users reported that CiviMail is not pushing their messages. The scheduled mailings have Started, but not Completed. When I go to scheduled jobs and manually execute the Send Scheduled Mailings, it refreshes the page but doesn't send the mail. When I go to my host control panel and initiate the Cron manually, I receive the following error:

**Notice**:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in **/home/mysite/www/www/includes/session.inc** on line **287**

I found a few "solutions" via Google that involve editing the session start php code.

For instance I entered this into the root php.ini file:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
```

It clears the error when running the cron manually, but it doesn't actually send the pending messages in Civi.

The log says:

> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:  Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with
>   result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error

There was another "solution" to add "php_flag session.auto_start 0" to the .htaccess file. When I tried that, it gave me server not found errors when trying to access the site.

I also cleared my _sessions table to see if that fixed the issue. No dice.

Does anyone have a possible solution to this issue? Thank you.

Civi 4.7.12
Drupal 7.51

Edit: 10-29-16 / 2159 to add log error message.

Comment: What is the result of running the *Send Scheduled Mailings* job?  It writes a message that you can examinate at the  *View Job Log* link.

Comment: Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error

Comment: That explains why the emails are not pushed. Maybe you can find more information in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/civimail-not-sending-mails-in-4-7-6-drupal-7-db-error-syntax-error

Comment: CiviCrm errors can be logged to drupal watchdog logging. But you have to enable it in *Administer CiviCRM -> Settings - Debugging and Error Handling*. This should give you the syntax of the sql statement that causes the DB Error. Maybe you can add it to the question for feedback.

Comment: Thank you! The messages have been sent after deleting and re-scheduling them. It looks like the solution was as described in your link. Issue resolved (at least on my end).

Answer (score 1):

Kainuk referenced [a post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/civimail-not-sending-mails-in-4-7-6-drupal-7-db-error-syntax-error) that I missed regarding this issue. It appears that after scheduling the mailings, users were deleted from the groups to whom those mailings were scheduled to send. A quick cancellation of those messages, then re-using them solved the issue.

Comment: Could you accept your own answer here, please?